# Problem with create the product user profile

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm connected as system user, when I tried to connect user `conn user/password` I get this messages

```
ERROR:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


Error accessing PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
Warning:  Product user profile information not loaded!
You may need to run PUPBLD.SQL as SYSTEM
Connected.
```

When i tried `@$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/pupbld.sql` I get this errors

```
SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/pupbld.sql

Session altered.

DROP SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01434: private synonym to be dropped does not exist


BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_OBJ1 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at line 21
ORA-06512: at line 2


DROP VIEW PRODUCT_PRIVS
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


  FROM SQLPLUS_PRODUCT_PROFILE
       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


GRANT SELECT ON PRODUCT_PRIVS TO PUBLIC
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM PRODUCT_PROFILE
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01432: public synonym to be dropped does not exist


CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM PRODUCT_PROFILE FOR SYSTEM.PRODUCT_PRIVS
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_OBJ1 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM


DROP SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01434: private synonym to be dropped does not exist


CREATE SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE FOR SYSTEM.SQLPLUS_PRODUCT_PROFILE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_OBJ1 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM


DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01432: public synonym to be dropped does not exist


CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE FOR SYSTEM.PRODUCT_PRIVS
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_OBJ1 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM



Session altered.
```

I hope I explained the problem clearly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original login problem is [well-known](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_warning_product_user_profile_information_not_loaded.htm), and indeed the solution is to run the  `pupbld.sql` script.

When it comes to the output of the script, you should ignore errors that relate to non-existant objects and focus on solving this one :

```
ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_OBJ1 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
```

You need to extend the tablespace so the script can properly run, which will finally enable user login.

Comment: I added a file to the tablespace system and works great

Answer (score 2):

This was giving me fits in a pluggable database (even with the help of Mr. Burleson's article.) Eventually I realized the problem was that when I connected to the system user, it kept connecting me to the **CDB** system user, so the script was running at the level of the CDB, not the PDB.

```
$ sqlplus pdb_user/password@PDB_NAME

(stupid warning thing here)

SQL> select * from global_name;
GLOBAL_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDB_NAME

SQL> conn system/password
Connected.

SQL> select * from global_name;
GLOBAL_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
CDB_NAME
```

The solution was to connect to the system user of the PDB explicitly ...

```
SQL> conn system/password@PDB_NAME
Connected.

SQL> select * from global_name;
GLOBAL_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDB_NAME
```

... then run the pupbld.sql script.